# How can I write only certain rows of an Excel worksheet to CSV?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, csv

I have created an Excel (2010) workbook that takes information from various CSV files and puts them into a format that can be understood by my office's scheduling program.  Using a macro I found online, I can save each sheet of the workbook as a separate CSV file, ready to import.

The problem is that many rows of the workbook are by necessity empty of information, since each row is devoted to a block of time that may or may not be scheduled.  These zero-filled rows cause the scheduler program to spit out errors.  This isn't a fatal problem, as "good" schedule entries are still imported, but it means I have to wade through hundreds of expected errors to find *actual* errors.

I was wondering if there was a way to export only certain rows of a sheet to CSV - for example, every row in which the contents of column A are non-zero.

For reference, here is the macro I am currently using to turn the worksheets into separate CSV files.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub WriteCSV()

    Dim iFile As Integer
    Dim strText As String, strFileName As String
    Dim lngCol As Long, lngRow As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    iFile = FreeFile()

    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wks.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            strFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & wks.Name & ".csv"
            Open strFileName For Output As #iFile
                For lngRow = 1 To wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                    For lngCol = 1 To wks.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                        Print #iFile, wks.Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Text & ",";
                    Next lngCol
                        Print #iFile,
                Next lngRow
            Close #iFile
        End If
    Next wks

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `For lngRow = 1 to wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count`, add this line:

`If Not IsNull(wks.Cells(l, 1).Value) And Trim(wks.Cells(l, 1).Value) <> "" Then`

Note that there is a lowercase "L", then a number one in the parenthesis. Then, before `Next lngRow`, put this line in:

`End If`

That should skip any rows with either null (nothing) or empty (i.e., only tabs or spaces) in the first column.